# I have issues with my code while checking for duplicated values in an javascript's Array & ignoring some of those duplicated values

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, conditional-statements

I'm try to accomplish two things:

- Checking for duplicated values in an array and returning `false`, if duplicated values are not found.
- Make a blacklist with certain duplicated values that will be ignored while checking for duplicated values.

I got the checking for duplicated values working like so:

```
validateDuplicates = () => {
    let names = [
        'freddy',
        'sonia',
        'john',
        'jane',
        'mathew',
        'jonas',
    ]

    while (names.length) {
        const name = names.shift();
        if (names.includes(name)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My problem is that when I add the blacklisted values it doesn't work. This is what I have tried some far:

```
validateDuplicates = () => {
    let names = [
        'freddy',
        'sonia',
        'john',
        'jane',
        'mathew',
        'jonas',
        'jonas',
    ]

    let blacklistedNames = ['freddy', 'jane'];

    while (names.length) {
        const name = names.shift();
        if (names.includes(name) && names.includes(blacklistedNames)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I need that it return 'false' when duplicated values are not found except those duplicated values included in the `blacklistedNames` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like I did not fully understand the problem. After discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203488/discussion-between-manuel-abascal-and-tristan-wiley) I realized the actual problem.

Essentially the problem can be summarized with the following:

> For every item in the array, if there exists a duplicate then return true.
>   Otherwise return false
>
> However. If that duplicated item is in the blacklist, return false anyways.

So, given this we can come up with the following code.

```
if (blacklistedNames.includes(name)) {
   return false
}

if (names.includes(name)) {
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to put names in the `blacklistedNames` that are not included in the `names` variable, but I get the same results.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal Ah, would you like to return `true` if there is a name in the list of blacklisted names? I'm not sure I understand the purpose of the blacklistedNames array.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The `blacklistedNames` array will be a couple of duplicated values that I want to ignore because it's expected to be duplicated. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal Hm. Then you want to return true if the item is duplicated, OR if the item is in the `blacklistedNames` array. I'll update my answer to reflect that

Comment: If I understand correctly, this should work properly.

Comment: Basically, what I need is to return `false`(I know it doesn't make much sense in this context, but the functionality is for another context) when there are duplicated values in the `names` array and the same the values duplicated are included in the `blacklistedNames`, I'm not sure if I'm explaining myself correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203488/discussion-between-manuel-abascal-and-tristan-wiley).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.some`

```js
let names = [
    'freddy',
    'sonia',
    'john',
    'jane',
    'mathew',
    'jonas',
    'jonas',
]

let blackList = ['mathew','jonas'];

let hasSuplicate = names.some((name,index,array)=>{
  return array.filter(item => !blackList.some(b=>b===name) && item===name).length > 1
});

console.log(hasSuplicate)
```

Comment: in one line : ```let hasDuplicate = names.some((name,index,array)=>(array.filter(item => !blackList.some(b=>b===name) && item===name).length > 1));```

Comment: ```Array.some``` is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to get `false` when no values are duplicated with the exception of those values in the blaclistedNames's array.
By the way, I realised that I duplicated Jonas name in the names array so I updated my code sample.

Comment: The code will return true if there are duplicated values in array which they are not in BlackList. Don't u look for this?

Comment: For every item in the array, if there is a duplicate then must return `true`.
Otherwise return `false`

However. If that duplicated item is in the blacklist, return `false` anyways.

Answer (score 1):

you have one problem, you are passing an `Array` to the function `includes` when it only accepts a primitive.

```
if (names.includes(name) && names.includes(blacklistedNames))
```

should be something like:

```js
validateDuplicates = () => {
  let names = [
    'freddy',
    'sonia',
    'john',
    'jane',
    'mathew',
    'jonas',
    'jonas',
  ]

  let blacklistedNames = ['freddy', 'jane'];

  while (names.length) {
    const name = names.shift();
    const isBlackListed = blacklistedNames.includes(name);
    if (names.includes(name) && !isBlackListed) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(validateDuplicates());
```

another solution could be to remove the items that are on the `blackListedNames` from the `names` array, therefore you check for duplicates on a clean array.

```js
validateDuplicates = () => {
  let names = [
    'freddy',
    'sonia',
    'john',
    'jane',
    'mathew',
    'jonas',
    'jonas',
  ]

  let blacklistedNames = ['freddy', 'jane'];

  names = names.filter(name => !blacklistedNames.includes(name))

  while (names.length) {
    const name = names.shift();
    if (names.includes(name)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(validateDuplicates());
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: It prints `true` whether I change the `blacklistedNames`'s values to a value that are not in the `names` Array.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal because it doesnt matter, because you are looking for duplicates on the names. we dont care if there are duplicates on the `blacklistedNames` or if a name is on the `blacklistedNames` but it is not on the `names`.